# Why does numpy.std() use abs()?

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

I checked the numpy library and found the following definition for the standard deviation in `numpy`:

```
std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2))
```

Why is the `abs()` function used? - Because mathematically the square of a number will be positive per definition.

So I thought:

```
abs(x - x.mean())**2 == (x - x.mean())**2
```

Comment: The docs say the following: 'Note that, for complex numbers, std takes the absolute value before squaring, so that the result is always real and nonnegative.'

Comment: @AlexRiley thanks. So would it be better (more performant) to use a different function for values, which are not complex?

Comment: @KevinWallis Maybe, but remember to profile first and see if it is a problem.

Comment: @KevinWallis: you should be fine - I think NumPy handles the complex cases separately to the real cases (cf. [this code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1368cbb696ae27b849eed67b4fd31c550a55dad5/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L412-L415) where the conjugate is computed separately to be used for `x*x` [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1368cbb696ae27b849eed67b4fd31c550a55dad5/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L424-L425)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square of a real number is always positive, but this is not true for complex numbers.

A very simple example: `j**2=-1`

A more complex (pun intended) example: `(3-2j)**2=(5-12j)`

From documentation:

> Note that, for complex numbers, `std` takes the absolute value before squaring, so that the result is always real and nonnegative.

Note:
Python uses `j` for the imaginary unit, while mathematicians uses `i`.